# How to remove redirection of pmpro to the levels pages

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

In buddy press, I used this filter but it did not work (from [here](https://gist.github.com/strangerstudios/98a7d58a81b5becd5d0f#file-pmpro_register_redirect-php))

```
add_filter('pmpro_register_redirect', '__return_false');
```

And how to restrict **ADD FRIENDS** in buddypress with help of Paid Membership pro plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your active theme `functions.php`

```
define("PMPRO_DEFAULT_LEVEL", "1");//in place of 1 you can put your default membership level id
```

and you are done.